# Parsing JSON object using javascript keeps returning 'undefined' for object with a dot in the name

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object with a single member 'jsonMember' which contains an array containing objects as follows:

```
jsonMember: [{"name":"GGLV-L014054","manufacturer.name":"TOSHIBA"},
{"name":"GGLV-W014329","manufacturer.name":"FUJITSU"}]
```

I am able to return 'name' but when making the same call for 'manufacturer.name' I get undefined.

I have tried a number of variations without any luck and I would really appreciate a helpful pair of eyes.

```
var parser = new JSONParser();
var parsed = parser.parse(jsonString);
    for (i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
        var name = parsed[i].name; //Works fine
        var manufacturer = parsed[i].manufacturer.name; //returns undefined
```

Comment: `parsed[i]['manufacturer.name']`

Answer (score 1):

change

`var manufacturer = parsed[i].manufacturer.name;`

to

```
 var manufacturer = parsed[i]["manufacturer.name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly formalize each internal object, you can't just use the `.` like that.

Try this

```
jsonMember: [{"name":"GGLV-L014054","manufacturer":{"name" : "TOSHIBA"}},  {"name":"GGLV-W014329","manufacturer": {"name" : "FUJITSU"} }]
```